# Image fails to load (sometimes!)

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a site using Boostrap and JQuery

The site works fine, there is this one image that fails to load, in a rather weird fashion. This is the HTML that defines it:

```
<img src="resources/publicidade/pub.png" width="100%"/>
```

However, when the site loads, it loads as this:

```
<img src="resources/publicidade/pub.png" width="0" height="0" style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 100px 1px;">
```

The image it loads when this happen is 1px x 1px, but my image is actually 1346px x 501px.

If I put the source path for the image on the web address, it loads fine. When I return to the webpage, the problem disappears!

Looking at the server log (I'm using python3 -m http.server) I find that when the error occurs, the line  GET /resources/publicidade/pub.png HTTP/1.1" 200  is not even there. There is no error message either. When I do the "load image and return" trick, the GET message is there, as expected.

I'm using github pages and the problem occurs there as well. I unfortunately can't post the link here since my client requested privacy. I tried clearing the cache and using a different browser, even a different OS but the problem still occurs.

Comment: you're using a relative path for your image, which can break depending on which page you are on. Try /resources/publicidade/pub.png. Also the additional styles on your img means there is some javascript that is probably affecting your image.

Comment: all the other images on the same page are relative as well and they don't behave in the same way. 
using the beginning / does not affect the bug. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adblock recognized my image was publicity because of the path name. Disabling adblock fixed my error.